# why os.remove isn't removing a file in python?

Tags: python

I have imported and installed all the libraries properly, and wrote the side code until here

```
def speak(audio_str):
    tts = gTTS(text=audio_str, lang='en')
    r = random.randint(1, 10000000)
    audio_file = 'audio-' + str(r) + '.mp3'
    tts.save(audio_file)
    playsound.playsound(audio_file)
    speak(audio_str)
    os.remove(audio_file)
```

when it came to executing:
`speak('How can I help you?')`
It played the sound but didn't remove the created voice file
any solutions?

Comment: `os.remove()` doesn't fail silently; if it was in fact called, and it failed, there will be an exception. We need that exception to be included in the question. If there's code your real program contains that you didn't include here that silently ignores exceptions, (1) don't do that; (2) make sure you're including as much code as necessary to get the exact same erroneous behavior as your real program when run without changes (and nothing beyond that).

Comment: Also, part (specifically, the "minimal" part) of building a [mre] is removing everything that isn't specifically necessary to reproduce the problem and test whether it has been fixed. If you can produce the problem without using gTTS, then gTTS shouldn't be in the question. If you can reproduce the problem without using `random.randint()`, then `random.randint()` shouldn't be in the question. If you can reproduce the problem without `playsound`, then `playsound' shouldn't be in the question; etc.

Comment: Also, notice how your code is recursing? How is it ever going to get to the `os.remove()` call if it has to do another call to `speak()` first (and that second call to `speak()` never gets to _its_ `os.remove()` call, because it too calls yet another `speak()` first).

Comment: That `speak(audio_str)` is unnecessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.remove()` isn't removing the file *because your code never reaches it*, because it recurses before it gets there.

Remove the `speak(audio_str)` immediately preceding.